# Using VSCode, how do I compare two non-consecutive commits on a file in Gitlens

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use Gitlens in VScode, I cannot find an option to compare commits on a file when they are not consecutive. If I use 'open changes' on a certain commit in the 'File History' panel, it always compares that version of the file with the previous one. Is there a way to choose to compare one revision of the file (and not necessarily the latest revision) with another revision of my choosing of that file?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to see past commits and compare up-to-date version with an older one? If so, try  `GitLens: Show File History in View` then select any version that you want to compare.

Comment: I think I should be able to select two revisions of the file (one being the latest revision or Not) with any other revision of the same file in the list of the revisions presented in the "File History" side bar panel, isn't that possible?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can compare two nonconsecutive commits via the following steps (assuming you have the Gitlens extension installed):

- Source Control tab (or Gitlens tab) -> Open the Branches menu.
- From the branches menu -> Open the branch of interest.
- Right click on a particular commit and select "Select for Compare"
- Similarly, find the other commit you're interested in, right click and select "Compare with Selected"

You will see that under the "Search & Compare" menu, your two different commits are compared.

---

**edit note:** you might not see a Gitlens tab anymore as it was (optionally) merged with the Source Control tab, in version 11.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I like to say if anyone just needs compare the file history, can go to the file history section. As Aaron mentioned, the key is first select the commit, right click the "Select for Compare", then select the another commit, right click "Compare with Selected". Took me some time to figure out what's the difference of these two menu items, So 1. Select for compare, 2. Compare with selected.

Comment: @Aaron B. – thank you so much! That was very helpful.  
  
Chiming in: I'd often like to perform a code review – to see exactly what my programmer did … just like in Gitlab with "Compare latest with master". To do so, I'd do the following:  
  
1. Checkout that branch.  
2. Merge master into that branch – no need to commit / push.  
3. On the "Compare Commits" pane, click the "Compare <branch, …>…" item:  
4. 1st select "Working Tree".  
5. 2nd select "Master".  
  
This way you will see everything that was changed in that branch. … You'll need to abort the merge afterwards.

Comment: Just want to add that I couldn't find the mentioned "Repositories" menu while I was trying to do the same in the latest VS code (version 1.58.2) on windows. It took me some time to realize that the latest version of VS code ships with a preinstalled Source Control tab but it DOES NOT have any of the above-mentioned advanced menu options by default. We need to install the latest Gitlens extension to enable these advanced menu options. Once Gitlens is installed, the same Source Control tab will have many advanced menus including "Repositories", "Search & Compare" etc.

Comment: @AaronB. Please upvote if the comment helped improve the answer in any way :). Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can do this on an individual commit basis as well, by using the `Commits` section instead of the `Branches` section.

Answer (score 19):

- First, install gitlens plugin
- Second, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, input `gitlens:compare references`
- Third, input 1<sup>st</sup> commit hash and 2<sup>nd</sup> commit hash

Then, in the right side bar, find *SEARCH & COMPARE*

You will find the two commits' diff details

[image: Commits' diff details]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without Gitlens:

1. Right click on the file
2. Choose "Commit Changes"
3. Choose "Open Changes with Revision..."
4. Then choose the commit you want to compare your file with.

Comment: The commit I want to compare to is not in the list with suggestions, and searching parts of the name or hash brings up nothing.

Answer (score 4):

In the explorer (VSCode explorer tab, not Windows explorer) right click on your file, and select 'Open Timeline'. Now with ctrl click select 2 points in time you want to compare and you'll see the diff.

You actually can select not only commits, the timeline also shows every save and stage moment.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to checkout one of the commits you want to diff in terminal

```
git checkout <commit_hash>
```

and the select the other comit in gitlens, click `open changes` to see diff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there must be a better/quicker way to do this rather than changing that branch every time.

Comment: You dont change branch, you just go to a different commit. But yes, I agree. There should be someway to do it in the UI, i just could not find it.

Answer (score -1):

You can open Git Graph then click on the commit of interest. That opens listing of the files, click on the file of interest and that will open an editor tab to compare.